# efficient way to encode a number in UTF - 8 - MQTT

Tags: optimization, encoding, utf-8, embedded, mqtt

A little conceptual question here, I have several devices (UC), each one whit a unique numeric ID, all those devices will send data trough MQTT, whit topics such as

IDx/data/etc

Where IDx would be the numeric identifier of the device, I have a few question about this setup, the topic in MQTT is encoded in UTF-8, my question is: ¿what is the efficient way to encode this number so it use the fewer number of ASCII characters? I was thinking in using base 64, but I'm not sure if exist a smartest way to encode this number so it use fewer digits

**Additional information**

- All this in the context of IoT, embedded systems and the track of those devices online
- The ID could be a number from 8 to 16 bytes

Comment: Express the number in decimal and then compress the whole thing at a higher level  (you may find the protocol already offers this).  It isn't worth spending any effort trying to efficiently hand pack just one little bit of the whole message.

Comment: @TomV When you say that I should compress in a higher level what do you mean? I want to compress this number to minimize the total size the MQTT packet, example, from the string "15"(decimal) to the string "F" (hexadecimal)

Comment: I mean: Are you really close to the limit that it matters? if so, compress the whole message, not individual fields.  If not don't waste time trying to be clever.

Comment: @TomV it's not the message payload, it's part of the topic that the message is published on, it can't be compressed as it is a field in the message header.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use MQTT v5 (and your client library supports it) then you don't need to worry about this at all, you can just use topic aliases.

The broker and the client work out pre-determined (as part of the first publish iirc or at subscribe time) numerical identifiers for the topics so the mapping is only sent once and then for all subsequent messages replaced by the id.

See this article for more details.

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt5-essentials-part10-topic-alias/